# R - elegant way to prepend text to vector elements in a dplyr pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a more elegant way to prepend text to each item in a vector in a dplyr pipe. I can append text easily with:

```
vec = c("AAA","BBB","CCC") %>% 
    paste0("_suffix")
```

but I need to break out of the pipe operation to prepend:

```
vec1 = c("AAA","BBB","CCC") 
vec1 <- paste0("prefix_", vec1)
```

Above is a greatly simplified example. I'm performing a number of %>% pipe operations before and after the prepend for a number of variables I'm extracting. It feels clumsy to have to break out of the pipe just to perform the prepend, and I know there'll be a simple and elegant way to do this.

```
var1 <- html %>% 
    html_nodes(".some_class") %>% 
    html_attr('href') %>% 
    #several more operations
    ...

var1 <- paste0(prefix_text, var1) %>% 
    #several more operations
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot to specify that the second, rather than first, argument is to be substituted in.

```
c("AAA","BBB","CCC") %>% paste0("prefix_", .)
## [1] "prefix_AAA" "prefix_BBB" "prefix_CCC"
```